# fscanf() without field width limits can crash with huge input data in C

Tags: c, scanf, warnings

I have an exercise in C. I wrote a function

```
int readArray(FILE *wp, char *name, int n, double M[n][n])
{
    fscanf(wp, "%s", &name[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            fscanf(wp, "%lf", &M[i][j]);
    return 1;
}
```

How can I change this? I have the following warning

```
warning: fscanf() without field width limits can crash with huge input data. [invalidscanf]
    fscanf(wp, "%s", &name[0]);
```

Comment: @user3121023 Thanks for the correction, i have removed my comment in order not to cause confusion. In that case, `scanf()` shouldn't be used at all with a user-provided buffer of variable length (or you'd have to generate the format string dynamically)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%s` placeholder is used to read a word into a string.

By default, there is no restriction on the length of that word. A field width specifier can be used together with the %s placeholder to limit the number of bytes which will by written to the buffer.

So you should do something like:

```
char name[100];
fscanf(wp, "%99s", name);
```

For example, if the length of `name` that you get from file is greater than 100, this function will overflow. The problem is similar to `scanf` also.

Answer (score 2):

It's not an error. It's a warning.

And you solve it by simply adding a limit to the field width, like this:

```
fscanf(wp, "%1234s", &name[0])
```

The value `1234` is just made up. The above code will read at most 1234 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

The message is warning you that that fscanf has no control on the input size, making possible to write data beyond target buffer size. In order to solve it just apply the length to `%s` format:

```
char name[50];

fscanf(wp, "%49s", &name[0]);
```

This makes sure that at most 49 characters are stored into name array (that in my example has size 50. One character has to be left to the string terminator).